# How to add time (data type) as parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I need to create a report that allows the user to give a date and time range for a report. I can set up the StartDate and EndDate (DateTime data type), but I can't seem to figure out how to add StartTime and EndTime.

This is a report where they want to view what was processed between a certain date *and time*. Is there anything that I can do so that the user can choose/enter a value for time in a report?

Comment: I fear you may have to provide date and time as separate parameters - I'm yet to see a date/time picker in SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

As @WillA mentioned in a comment, there is no date **+** time picker in SSRS. However, the datepicker that comes with a DateTime parameter does allow manually entering a time component.

First, here's what happens if you select just a date in the picker:

[image: select only a date]

If you render this in a TextBox with format string `` HH:mm:ss, MMM d `yy ``, this will become:

> 00:00:00, Dec 9 `12

However, if the user *manually* :'( enters a time component it *will* work, e.g.

[image: select a time as well]

This will be rendered (with the same format) as such:

> 15:27:00, Dec 9 `12

This is not a very user-friendly solution though.

Comment: If I recall correctly, if you set a default value that includes a time, such as `=DateAdd("s", .01, Today())` (a millisecond after midnight) then the time will be displayed when the user brings up the report. This helps the user to know they can type a time in.

Alternately, I have used a drop down with hours, so the user selects a date and and hour (from 24) with two parameters.